# JsInterop: _framework/blazor.server.js doesn't recognize .datetimepicker() function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

When the datetimepicker function is being called, blazor.server.js sends a error with:  **Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: $(...).datepicker is not a function TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a functiemphasized texton.** .This is a example how the website works:

Index.cshtml

```
@using System.Diagnostics
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding
@using ReservationGuest.Components
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.standalone.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.nl.min.js"></script>


@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Component>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
<script src="js/button.js"></script>
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

Component.razor

```
<div>
  <input @onclick="NextDiv" id="3" type="button" value="volgende" class="buttons btn btn-primary" style="float:right" />

</div>
<form method="post">
    <div id="div2" class="divs CHidden" style="background-color: #ffffff;   width: 65%; height: 37%;  margin-left: 18%; margin-top: 62px; padding: 1% 4% 7% 1%;">
        <h1>Datum</h1>
        <div style=" margin-left: 23px;">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div id="input-daterange" class="input-group input-daterange">
                        <div class="input-group-addon"></div>
                        <input type="hidden" @bind="CreateRes.date" class="input-group-addon form-control" />

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          <input @onclick="NextDiv" id="3" type="button" value="volgende" class="buttons btn btn-primary" style="float:right" />
      </div>
    </div>
</form>

    async Task NextDiv()
    {
        if (IsValidEmail(CreateRes.Email) != false)
        {          await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("NextDiv");


        }
    }
```

button.js.

```
function NextDiv() {
    $("div[class=divs]").hide();
    $("div[id=div4]").hide();
    number += 1;
    DateDiv();
    var n = number.toString();
    $("div[id=div"+n+"]").removeClass('CHidden');
    $("div[id=div" + n + "]").show();

}

function DateDiv() {
    var SelectedDates = {};
    SelectedDates[new Date('04/05/2019')] = new Date('04/05/2016');
    SelectedDates[new Date('05/04/2017')] = new Date('05/04/2017');
    SelectedDates[new Date('06/06/2018')] = new Date('06/06/2018');
    var nowDate = new Date();
    var today = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

    $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
        format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
        startDate: new Date(),
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        language: 'nl'

    });

}
```

Does someone know how to let blazor.server.js recognize or know where the links for bootstrap-datepicker are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the jquery script on host, try deleting the script from your index page,

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
```

I suppose it doesn't work if it is duplicated, it worked for me try it and tell me. I don't know if deleting from the host would also work